# Irreducibility of a quartic polynomial

Tags: polynomials

How can one show that the polynomial 
$$x^4+x^3+3$$
is irreducible in $\Bbb{Q}[x]$? I only know Eisenstein criterion, but it doesn't apply directly. Of course I verified that there are no rational roots - but how can I exclude that it's a product of two irreducible quadratic polynomials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple approach is to remark that $x^4+x^3+3$ is irreducible modulo $2$. Indeed, $x^4+x^3+1\pmod{2}$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_2$ and is not divisible by $x^2+x+1$.

Thus, your polynomial is also irreducible over the rationals.